# symfony2 / doctrine, use custom values for entity form type

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, entities

i have the following problem with symfony forms.

i have two entitites with one to many relations. Advert and ReleaseDates. The second one has only two fields, foreign key advert_id and release_date which is a datetime type.

On my form for creating Advert i want to show checkboxes with all possible date values, and on form submit appropriate rows should be created. the values for available dates stored in another table, but there is no relation between them.

what i am currently have

```
->add('releaseDates', 'choice', array(
        'multiple' => true, 
        'expanded' => true, 
        'choices' => $options['rdl'],
        'constraints' => new Count(array('min' => 1, 'minMessage' => 'Choose at least one release date')),
)
```

but i got an error like "Expected an array" when rendering a form.

i have tried also other ways,

```
->add('releaseDates', 'order_release_dates', array(
    'multiple' => true, 
    'expanded' => true, 
    'class' => 'MyBundle:ReleaseDate', 
    'choices' => $options['rdl'],
    'property' => 'releaseDate',
    'constraints' => new Count(array('min' => 1, 'minMessage' => 'Choose at least one release date')),
)
```

but still without any success "Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given".

so what is my question, is there any solution for this, or i should manually handle the submit and create necessary entities?

Comment: try form type `entity` instead of `choice`, http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: the second code snippet is used custom form type, with entity as a parent type

Comment: What kind of data is in `$options['rdl']`?

Comment: its just an array with possible date values